# Rails class forgets its class variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class which lives in lib/my_class.rb:

```
class MyClass
  @@val = nil
  def self.configure(val)
    @@val = val
  end

  def self.getval
    @@val
  end
end
```

In config/initializers/my_class.rb:

```
MyClass.configure(314)
SOME_VAR = 314
```

However, if I open a rails console, I see the following result:

```
MyClass.getval
> nil
SOME_VAR
> 314
MyClass.configure(123)
MyClass.getval
> 123
```

What's even stranger is that, if I move `MyClass.configure(314)` into environment.rb, I can run `MyClass.getval` in a console and it returns 314 as expected. Even still, the rails server will randomly "forget" the value stored, causing me to need to restart the server. I would think that it's reloading the class file, causing it to reset its state.

I did some looking around and couldn't find any other examples of the issue. I am on Rails 6.

Comment: I don't have an answer but it's worth noting that any `environment/*.rb` file will be ran before initializers

Comment: are you running thread safe code or multithreaded server? what server are you running in production?

Comment: @CarlMarkham I'm adding the line after "Rails.application.initialize!", I'm not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: @lacostenycoder I'm running thread safe code. There is no production yet.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in rails are ephemeral they don't need to save state after have being used. This is not a good paradigm, you must initialize your clases with the initialize method and only when you are going to access them. Also the configuration of the class must start in the initialize method

```rb
class MyClass
 attr_reader :some_var
 def initialize(:some_var)
   @some_var = some_var
 end
end
```

This will provide you a way to get the value by typing

```rb
my_cool_class = MyClass.new(some_var: 'This class is awesome')
# Then you can access the some var with
puts my_cool_class.some_var # Output => 'This class if fucking awesome'
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't want there to be multiple instances of the class. Also, looking at Ruby gems, it seems fairly common to handle configuration by doing something along the lines of `TheirClass.configure { |c| c.their_var = "whatever" }`